# How to pass a collection of objects into a method that takes in collection of base objects?

Tags: c#

Say I have this method

```
 public void test(IList<AvaliableFeaturesVm> vm)
        {

        }
```

I have this class that inherits my base class

```
public class TravelFeaturesVm : AvaliableFeaturesVm
    {

    }
```

how do I pass it into method "test". If test only accepted one AvaliableFeatureVm object it would let me pass in a TravelFeaturesVm object but since they are in a collection it does not let me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of C# 4, you can do this *if* you change the signature of the first call to:

```
public void test(IEnumerable<AvaliableFeaturesVm> vm)
{
}
```

This is due to [*generic covariance*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) which was introduced in C# 4. `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant in `T` in C# 4, but `IList<T>` is *invariant*, so it won't as-is. If you're not using C# 4, this won't work anyway.

This is assuming that all your method needs to do is iterate over the collection. If it needs to *modify* the collection, then it wouldn't be safe to pass in a list of the subtype anyway - because the method could try to add either an instance of the base class, or of a different subtype.

Another alternative is to make the method itself generic:

```
public void test<T>(IList<T> vm) where T : AvaliableFeaturesVm
```

Of course, this has its own limitations - in particular, again you won't be able to write:

```
vm.Add(new AvailableFeaturesVm());
```

... although you *can* do:

```
AvailableFeaturesVm first = vm[0];
```

as the constraint ensures that there's an appropriate conversion from `T` to `AvailableFeaturesVm`.

For more on generic variance, see [Eric Lippert's blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/).

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski: Interfaces and delegates.

Answer (score 3):

You can make it generic:

```
public void test<T>(IList<T> vm) where T : AvaliableFeaturesVm
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

declare your collection to be a collection of `AvaliableFeaturesVm`. this will allow you to put `TravelFeaturesVm`-objects in the collection, and it will allow you to pass the collection to your method :)